# What does = ? mean in H2 / SQL Database Query

Tags: mysql, sql, h2

While I was looking at an example tutorial I saw some H2/SQL queries.

I saw this where `<column> = ?` in some of the queries

The query is

```
select * from events, owner
where events.owner = owner.id and (events.owner = ?)
```

I understand what most of it means except the last part where it says and **(events.owner = ?)**

Can someone briefly explain what it means? Thank you! (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the standard syntax for prepared statements, which expect parameters.

See the [JDBC tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) for more information about prepared statements. They're a best practice to follow to correctly escape special characters, reuse the same query several times without recomputing the execution plan every time, and the most important: avoid [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: Ohh okay thank you!!! I didn't realize it was being used for the prepared statement.

Answer (score 0):

This Wikipedia article explains ? marks. They are used for what is called Prepared Statements.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement